# import and export excel file (csv, xls and xlsx) from database by linq

Tags: c#, database, excel, linq-to-entities

Does someone know how to export an excel file (csv, xls and xlsx) from database (sql server 2008). Better is using linq to entity and c#.net.

furthermore, I also need retrieve back the excel file (csv, xls and xlsx) and store into database as well.

It is better if not using third party source.

Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use library like epPlus http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks Brijesh Mishra. but i dun think this can be suit for the 2003 version user.... anyway, thanks for help:)

Answer (score 1):

But you can use the SQL Server itself to export to Excell. watch [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952922%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, O.D, it is can use coding dynamically generated?